# Expected value of $x^TAx$

Tags: statistics

I have a question on this specific question from the past entrance examination of a university.

https://www.ism.ac.jp/senkou/kakomon/math_20190820.pdf

I assume that the mean vector of the d-dimensional vector $x$ is $0_d$, and the variance-covariance matrix is $I_d$.

Then, I would like to calculate $E[x^TAx]$.

Here,

- $x$ is a column vector,
- $A$ is a d-dimensional square matrix,
- $0_d$ is a d-dimensional zero vector,
- $I_d$ is a d-dimensional identity matrix.

Comment: What have you tried? You should state more than the problem itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked the rule that I had to write what I tried. I'll be careful next time. (In this case, I tried to use $\sum_{ij} = E[x_ix_j] - E[x_i]E_[x_j]$, but after that I didn't know what to do.)

Comment: Your work/thoughts should be in the main post, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^TAx=\sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^d a_{ij}x_ix_j$ where $a_{ij}$ are elements of $A$.

Then use linearity of expectation and given variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You mean $E[x^TAx] = \sum^d_{i=1}\sum^d_{j=1} a_{ij}E[x_ix_j] = \sum^d_{i=1}\sum^d_{j=1} a_{ij} (\sigma_{ij} + \mu_i\mu_j)$ (and use $0_d$ and $I_d$), right? It seems to be solved, thank you!

Comment: Right. When $\sigma_{ij}$ comes from identity matrix and $\mu_i$ are zero, the expression can be simplified significantly.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. Finally, I got $E[x^TAx] = \sum^d_i [A\sum]_{ii} + \mu^TA\mu = tr(AI_d) + \mu^TA\mu = tr(A)$!

Comment: Yes, it is right.